# Create inverse of each column in pandas dataframe and add prefix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
```

I'd like to add inverses of each existing column to the dataframe and name them based on existing column names with a prefix, e.g. `inv_A` is an inverse of column `A` and so on.

The resulting dataframe should look like so:

```
df_inv = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "inv_A": [1/1, 1/2, 1/3], "inv_B": [1/4, 1/5, 1/6]})
```

Obviously there are redundant methods like doing this in a loop, but there should exist much more pythonic ways of doing it and after searching for some time I didn't find anything. I understand that this is most probably a duplicate; if so, please point me to an existing answer.

Comment: Near-duplicate: [Pandas Dataframe - Replace column values with reciprocal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388334/pandas-dataframe-replace-column-values-with-reciprocal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try :

```py
inv_df = df.join(df.apply(lambda x: 1/x).add_prefix('inv_'))
```

Or as @Erfan suggested, you don't need to use apply :

```
inv_df = df.join((1/df).add_prefix('inv_'))
```

This gives :

```py
inv_df
Out[70]: 
   A  B     inv_A     inv_B
0  1  4  1.000000  0.250000
1  2  5  0.500000  0.200000
2  3  6  0.333333  0.166667
```

Comment: Glad I've been of help

Comment: No need for apply here: `df.join((1/df).add_prefix('inv_'))`

Comment: thank you @Erfan I wasn't sure that would work , I will update my answer accordingly

Comment: @Erfan please post that as an answer, or else AyoubZarou please edit into your answer and acknowledge Erfan. PS it only works if all columns of the df are numeric.

Comment: Thank you @smci for pointing that out, I just didn't think that was necessary as it's about approximatively the same thing

Comment: @AyoubZAROU: on a large df, it's probably more efficient than executing an individual Python lambda for every cell.